# Why did Rick burp less frequently in season 2?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, character-development, rick-and-morty

In the brilliant sci-fi cartoon *Rick and Morty*, one of Rick's most obvious idiosyncrasies is his [constant, mid-sentence burping](http://thecreatorsproject.vice.com/blog/the-painful-secret-behind-rick-and-mortys-burps).  However, [this quirk](http://io9.com/the-burps-are-real-while-doing-all-of-ricks-dialogue-f-1543965842) was far more pronounced in the first season than the second.

Have Dan Harmon (co-creator) or Justin Roiland (co-creator and the voice of Rick) commented on why Rick burps less in season two?

Comment: I wonder why this got downvoted. It's like a whole season of Flintstones without Fred saying "yabba dabba doo" or a whole season of The Walking Dead without Rick eye-humping the camera.

Comment: Did he drink less in season 2? Or did he still get Rickidy Rickidy Ricked?

Comment: @CandiedMango - He might have been slightly more sober, but if so, only by a hair.  And probably not even that much.

Comment: Because it's gross and they were trying to tone it down a bit? Seriously... I could barely make it through the first episode because of how gross Rick was but the subsequent episodes were significantly less gross (IMHO).

Comment: It was probably on request of the produces to tone down some of Rick's quirky speech behaviours, like they asked him to reduce the amount of times he says 'Morty'

Comment: @shea - Two of the many little hilarious idiosyncrasies that made Rick a riot.  :(

Answer (score 14):

According to [this random link](http://thecreatorsproject.vice.com/blog/the-painful-secret-behind-rick-and-mortys-burps), Justin Roiland said:

> The pilot, that was the worst. For some reason I was like, 'Rick has to burp every fucking line.' So I was in there for four hours recording Rick, and just swallowing air and doing every single line with a burp take. I left that studio with the worst stomach ache. I went home and laid in bed and thought I was going to fucking die or have to go to the hospital, it was seriously bad. And the irony is that we cut the radio play together and Harmon was like, 'There are way too many fucking burps in this,' and I was like, 'Oh fuck, you're right! This is disgusting.

Mainly, burping is painful to Roiland, and they probably decided that just a few very well placed burps could do better than some frequent eructing.

Answer (score -2):

I think Rick’s burping and vomiting were a major stumbling block to fully enjoying that otherwise amazing show. Rick’s burping and vomiting was probably the crack in the overall structure of the show that started to drive viewing down, preventing the show from becoming a longer running series like The Simpsons, or Family Guy. I have made posts in my social media about Rick and Morty, and talked to friends about the show, and complaints about Rick’s burping and vomiting were the most common complaint.

Comment: Can you find a source indicating that they changed it due to negative feedback? The existing answers suggests there was a different reason.